# How to prevent a label font size from resizing its parent?

Tags: javafx

I have a label inside a stackpane. This label represents the users font selection, and the size of the labels font is bound.

[image]

When the desired font size becomes too big, the label cuts itself off horizontally, but it pushes down vertically:

[image]

Setting pref/max height of the parent stackpane or the label does not prevent it growing vertically. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Minimal Example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo extends Application {

    private SimpleDoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(12);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Label label = new Label("font name");
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffeded;");
        label.prefWidth(120);
        label.maxWidth(120);
        label.prefHeight(32);
        label.maxHeight(32);
        fontSize.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                label.setFont(new Font(Font.getDefault().getName(), (Double) newValue));
        });

        StackPane sp = new StackPane(label);
        sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff9595;");
        sp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        sp.prefWidth(120);
        sp.maxWidth(120);
        sp.prefHeight(32);
        sp.maxHeight(32);

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setMin(8);
        slider.setMax(72);
        slider.setValue(12);
        fontSize.bind(slider.valueProperty());


        VBox box = new VBox(sp, slider);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 350, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Indent Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Expected behaviour: The label will cut off its text when it tries to grow outside the bounds of 120 x 32.

Comment: hach ... took a moment (and had to actually run it, thanks for the example :) - you are using the wrong methods: prefHeight(double) will return the pref appropriate for the given width, without changing anything. If you insist on hard-coding the sizing hints, use the setters. Which is not the whole story: if the label's min gets > its pref, it will be increased by the layout. So you have to fixate it as well, best with the use-pref-size marker (for both min/max when hard-coding pref)

Comment: That did it! Silly me on the method names. If you want to make this comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: you can answer it yourself to practice the names <g>